# PHP email form validation

Tags: php, email, validation

I am working on a comment form for a website and trying to secure against spammers. I have taken the validEmail function from this [link](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9585?page=0,3).

I am not very experienced at using functions. Is this the proper way to call the function and validate the user's email address? Any suggestions appreciated. Thank you

```
$email = $_POST['email'];

if (validEmail($email)) {

$to      = 'fsddfsdfa@gmail.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com';

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

print "Form submitted successfully: <br>Your name is <b>".$_POST['cname']."</b> and your email is <b>".$_POST['email']."</b><br>";

} else {

print "There was an error with your form submission.";

}
```

Comment: Really there are a lot of great answers to this question. Thank you very much for expanding on the concepts. I chose the answer provided by @vivid-colours because: it directly answered how to call the function and it was the first response. However, I believe that I will utilize FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL based on the opinions and information provided. This is a case where I wish I could award multiple correct answers. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function containing `validEmail( $email );` should be included into you file:

`include "whatever.php"`

(Or, you could copy and paste the function into the same file as your code)

Your `if` statement should look something like this:

```
if( validEmail( $email ) ) {
  // print your success message here
} else {
  // print your fail message here
}
```

In answer to your comment below, you can also write the above like this:

```
if( validEmail( $email ) === true ) {
  // print your success message here
} else {
  // print your fail message here
}
```

Comment: So call the function like this? Do I have to check to see if isValid returns a true value or is that implied? The last line of the function returns $isValid. Thanks

Comment: Hi Nick, I've expanded my solution to help :).

Comment: Thank you definitely answered my question. Is using FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL a better method for completing this process? thanks

Comment: To be honest.. I do prefer `if( !filter_var( $email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ) ) { ... }` yes.

Answer (score 3):

PHP has, since 5.2.0, its own validation filters that can be used to check whether the user has entered a proper e-mail address. There is no need to rely on things that you find on the internet for that purpose, since these functions can be flawed or broken. To use filter_var() for e-mail validation, the solution would be:

```
if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ 
    print "E-mail is correct";
} else {
    print "E-mail is not correct";
}
```

(also note that your original example code in the question had a missing semi-colon in one of the prints).

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing this out. I will most likely use FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL for my form. I would award multiple correct answers if possible, but had to award to vivid-colours because they explained how to call the function, and also answered first. Thank you for helping

Answer (score 1):

That whole linked `validEmail()` function can be replaced with:

```
function validEmail($email)
{
    if (filter_var('bob@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== false) {
        $domain = preg_split("/@/", $email);
        $domain = $domain[count($domain) - 1];
        if (checkdnsrr($domain,"MX") || checkdnsrr($domain,"A")) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

though I'm just taking the `checkdnsrr()` function from the article you linked.  I'm not familiar with it and I haven't used it for anything before.  The built-in `filter_var()` function is probably all you really would want to use, as checking DNS takes time (so every time someone submits something to your form, your script would possibly do 2 DNS lookups).

Comment: Should I use FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL as the other commenter suggested? Or is this a better way to validate?

Comment: Well, as you notice I also used `filter_var()` with `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`.  I just combined that with the DNS checking the function that you linked to in your question used.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Tried to offer as many points towards your rep as possible. Really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

```
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo "e-Mail is Valid";
} else {
    echo "Invalid e-Mail";
}
```